# How to remove duplicate phone numbers within one Android contact

Tags: contacts

Under many of the contacts on my phone I have pages full of the same phone number and/or email address.  Is there an automated method to remove them?

*Please note,* I'm not talking about duplicate contact records.  I'm talking about one contact record having multiple phone number entries with the same number filling multiple pages.   I could press the "-" button dozens of times to remove them, but this issue is happening on many of my contacts.

Googling this issue only returns results regarding "duplicate contacts" with suggestions of merging.  I'm not looking to merge contacts.  I'm looking to remove duplicate numbers that are listed under a single named contact.

When I went to Gmail's website to look up the contact for the person in the image I attached, Gmail only lists their email address (once) with no phone number.  I'm not sure where the other numbers are coming from or if there is a way to organize the contacts outside of my phone.  I'm interested in hearing options you may suggest.  I'm a developer and not afraid of an export/cleanup/import scenario if that is viable.

[image: duplicated numbers under one contact]

I have a Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use apps like Contacts Optimizer (available on google play) to link contacts with same phone numbers into one. There should also a similar feature built-in in the contacts app on your phone.

Comment: How does this apply to a single contact with a single phone number listed multiple times?

Comment: @gordon0525 Thanks for your input but this answer is not useful.  The duplicate numbers already exist under one contact.

Comment: Contacts Optimizer should be able to identify this matter. You should give it a try.

Comment: I tried Contacts Optimizer.  In the first pass it only addressed duplicate contact records.  I wrote to the authors and was told that the free version should support removing duplicate numbers within one contact so I ran it a second time.  After that the duplicate phone numbers were gone.   This solved my issue.  http://www.mobiledit.com/contacts-optimizer

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use the ''Google Contacts App'' on your browser instead of the third party apps.

You can find the Google Contacts within your Gmail account as well. Else, you can just search Google contacts.

The feature allows to remove the duplicate entries of the contacts in your Google Contacts. Also, it prompts you to merge the contacts with the same name.

Comment: _Please note_ that this issue isn't about duplicate contact records.  As far as I could tell the "Google Contacts App" would not remove duplicate phone numbers within one contact.  As noted in my original question, the duplicate numbers didn't even show up in the website view of the contact. They only appeared on my phone.
Thanks for your suggestion.  At first glance it's easily misunderstood that this issue is distinctly different from the common "I have duplicate contacts" issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **Contacts Optimizer**. In the first pass it only addressed duplicate contact records. I wrote to the authors and was told that the free version should support removing duplicate numbers within one contact so I ran it a second time. After that the duplicate phone numbers were gone. This solved my issue.

Comment: I downloaded the free version of Contacts Optimizer, but it didnt have the ability to remove duplicate phone numbers (not duplicate contacts, which it does). There are some options in the tool that look like it might address the duplicate number issue, but they require purchasing the app to explore them. What options did you select to get it to remove duplicate phone numbers? Thanks.

Comment: I don't recall setting any specific options.  It was odd to me that running it a second time had a different effect.  Sorry I can't be more help.